# How do I capture a variable in Linq method syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq query...

```
Proposals.OrderByDescending (p => p.ID)
  .First ()
  .Proposal_ProductConfigurations
  .Select(ppc => ppc.ProductConfigurationHistory)
  .Where(pch => pch.Active)
  .Select(pch => pch.ProductConfiguration)
  .Where(pc => pc.Active)
  .SelectMany(pc => pc.ProductConfigurations_PriceBookEntries)
  .Where(pcpb => pcpb.Active)
  .OrderBy(pcpb => pcpb.PriceBook.ProductCode)
  .GroupBy(pcpb => pcpb.PriceBook.ID)
  .Select (pcpb => new {
    Code = pcpb.First().PriceBook.ProductCode,
    Description = pcpb.First().PriceBook.Description,
    Quantity = pcpb.Sum (pcpb1 => (pcpb1.Quantity ?? 0)),
  })
```

...which is not quite right, as the ppc.Quantity entity has a Quantity property that needs to be used in the last line.

What I really want to do is something line this...

```
Quantity = pcpb.Sum (pcpb1 => (pcpb1.Quantity ?? 0) * ppc.Quantity),
```

...but of course I can't, as ppc is not in scope.

How would I capture the ppc.Quantity and use it in the last line? I think this could be done with fluent syntax, but I never use it, and haven't managed to produce any code that the compiler liked!

Comment: This Linq makes my brain hurt. You're traversing what appears to be a very complicated object structure in one line. Have you considered breaking this out into steps? Which, incidentally, would let you save off 'ppc' (whatever that is) at an earlier step and then re-use it at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can simplify the following part

```
.Select(ppc => ppc.ProductConfigurationHistory)
.Where(pch => pch.Active)
.Select(pch => pch.ProductConfiguration)
.Where(pc => pc.Active)
```

to

```
.Where(ppc => ppc.ProductConfigurationHistory.Active
              && ppc.ProductConfigurationHistory.ProductConfiguration.Active)
```

And you'll maintain the resulting collection of `ppc` instead of `pc`.

At this point you'll want to use the `SelectMany` overload that has a result selector as well as a collection selector to keep the `ppc`

```
.SelectMany(
    ppc => ppc.ProductConfigurationHistory
              .ProductConfiguration
              .ProductConfigurations_PriceBookEntries,
    (ppc, pcpb) => new { ppc, pcpb })
```

Then you just have to work with that new anonymous class and you'll get this

```
Proposals.OrderByDescending (p => p.ID)
  .First ()
  .Proposal_ProductConfigurations
  .Where(ppc => ppc.ProductConfigurationHistory.Active
                && ppc.ProductConfigurationHistory.ProductConfiguration.Active)
  .SelectMany(
    ppc => ppc.ProductConfigurationHistory
              .ProductConfiguration
              .ProductConfigurations_PriceBookEntries,
    (ppc, pcpb) => new { ppc, pcpb })
  .Where(anon => anon.pcpb.Active)
  .OrderBy(anon => anon.pcpb.PriceBook.ProductCode)
  .GroupBy(anon => anon.pcpb.PriceBook.ID)
  .Select (grp => new {
    Code = grp.First().pcpb.PriceBook.ProductCode,
    Description = grp.First().pcpb.PriceBook.Description,
    Quantity = grp.Sum(anon => (anon.pcpb.Quantity ?? 0) * anon.ppc.Quantity),
  })
```

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant! Thanks. I didn't know about that overload (still learning Linq), and didn't think of capturing the object in an anon type. very neat.